# Docker: can not communicate between containers

Tags: php, node.js, docker, nginx, proxy

I have a Docker setup with a php-fpm container, a node container and an nginx container which serves as a proxy. Now in the browser (http://project.dev), the php container responds with json like I expect. All good. However, when I make a request from the node container to this php container ([view code](https://github.com/thomastilkema/docker-nginx-php-fpm-node/blob/master/node/src/index.js#L8)), I get an error on the request: `ECONNRESET`. So apparently, the node container can not communicate with the php container. The nginx error does not seem to add an entry.

```
Error: read ECONNRESET at _errnoException(util.js: 1031: 13) at TCP.onread(net.js: 619: 25)
errno: 'ECONNRESET',
code: 'ECONNRESET',
syscall: 'read'
```

Any ideas?

I've made a github repo: https://github.com/thomastilkema/docker-nginx-php-fpm-node

*Trimmed version of [docker-compose.yml (view file)](https://github.com/thomastilkema/docker-nginx-php-fpm-node/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)*

```
nginx:
  depends_on:
    - php-fpm
    - node
  networks:
    - app
  ports:
    - 80:80

php-fpm:
  networks:
    - app

node:
  networks:
    - app

networks:
  app:
    driver: overlay
```

*Trimmed version of [nginx.conf (view file)](https://github.com/thomastilkema/docker-nginx-php-fpm-node/blob/master/nginx/nginx.conf)*

```
http {
  upstream php-fpm {
    server php-fpm:9000;
  }

  upstream node {
    server node:4000;
  }

  server {
    listen 80 reuseport;
    server_name api.project.dev;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
      ...
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name project.dev;

    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://node;
    }
  }
}
```

[php-fpm/Dockerfile (view file)](https://github.com/thomastilkema/docker-nginx-php-fpm-node/blob/master/php-fpm/Dockerfile)

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Request which gives an error

```
const response = await axios.get('http://php-fpm:9000');
```

*How to reproduce*

- [Create a swarm manager (and a worker) node](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-w-machine/)
- Find out the ip address of your swarm manager node (usually `192.168.99.100`): `docker-machine ip manager` or `docker-machine ls`. Edit your hosts file (on a Mac, `sudo vi /private/etc/hosts`) by adding `192.168.99.100 project.dev` and `192.168.99.100 api.project.dev`
- `git clone https://github.com/thomastilkema/docker-nginx-php-fpm-node project`
- `cd project ./scripts/up.sh`
- Have a look at the logs of the container: `docker logs <container-id> -f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ECONNRESET` is the other end closing the connection which can usually be attributed to a protocol error.

The FastCGI Process Manager (FPM) uses the [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) protocol to transport data.

Go via the nginx container, which translates the HTTP request to FastCGI

```
axios.get('http://nginx/whatever.php')
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, this indeed fixes my issue. I now get the response I expect.